# Analytics not recognized

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Been following the Firebase setup [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start). The setup process worked, but my project doesn't recognize the `Analytics` type:

```
Analytics.logEvent // use of unresolved identifier 'Analytics'
```

Xcode autocomplete shows `AnalyticsConfiguration`, but nothing else. As a sanity check, here's what I did to set up my project:

1. Use cocoapods to fetch `Firebase/Core`
2. Ensure I'm using the `.xcworkspace` file
3. Added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` for my project
4. In my app delegate, import `Firebase` and call `FirebaseApp.configure()`

Comment: Try importing it in the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized what the problem was. My project name was "Analytics", and it somehow influenced the visibility of the framework named "Analytics".